# Kivy module not found in vscode (Mac)

Tags: python, macos, user-interface, visual-studio-code, kivy

I have installed Kivy and when I used the IDLE app that came with Python I can import it and it runs perfectly. However, when I try to import it in vscode I get the error:
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'kivy'. I can not find out what to do and the environment from the kivy dmg does not open so I feel lost. Can someone help me?

Comment: check the python interpreter being used in vscode and if its the same as the one where kivy is installed

Comment: How do I do that? And if it isn't, how do I change it without having to change all my other pieces of code?

Comment: @MOStudios What do you suggest?

Comment: The platform I was using was a chromebook, but the location of changing the editor is the same

Comment: I've made it into an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Two solutions

### Check the python interpreter being used

When any `.py` file is open in the editor and is currently being used, near the bottom left, it says `Python <version> <32/64>-bit`. Tap it and select the directory that contains the python interpreter version that has kivy installed.

Check the following image for any help

[image: Click on the highlighted area in the bottom left]

The platform I was using was a chromebook, but the location of changing the editor is the same

### Manually install within VScode

Run `pip install kivy` to ensure that vscode uses it

Answer (score 0):

I got this error in VScode.I was using venv for kivy. It got resolved when I selected python interpreter in VScode (bottom right) from venv installed location \kivy_venv\Scripts\python.exe